# Delete specific id from table pg_largeobject Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Im trying to truncate some of our tables (some of them contains OID column type) from postgresql DB but i found that i have to delete also the Id of oid  columns from pg_largeobject table ,is their a way to delete this specific IDs from pg_largeobject ?

an example : department (identifier : int , name: varchar , description : OID)

**My target is delete the IDs Of description from pg_largeobject**

Cordially,

Comment: I think you are looking for `lo_unlink(...)`  (and convert that column to a `text` - there is really hardly any reason to use large objects - especially for something called "description")

Comment: thanks for replying , it's just an example to explain my target .thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the `lo_unlink` function.

To delete all large in the database, you can

```
SELECT lo_unlink(oid) FROM pg_largeobject_metadata;
```

It is a good idea to get rid of large objects.

Comment: Ok, I have adapted the query.

Comment: this query will delete all the IDs or just the IDs that linked to department ? cause i need to delete a specific IDs in pg_largeobject after truncated the table department, Thanks

Comment: If `departments` is truncated, there are no more links to any large objects; that information is lost. My query deletes **all** large objects. If there are some you still need, you'll have to figure out which ones.

Comment: thanks for reply , so do you mean that i don't have any way to get the oid ID to delete them from pg_largeobject  if the table department is truncated ?

Comment: That is precisely what I mean.